# Iterate through Json array

Tags: jquery, json

**Edit**
This is the function where I get the response from

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

  $.ajax({
    method: "get",
    url: 'ctr_seearmylist.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: 'get=squad',
    success: processSquads
  });

});
```

and this is the php snippet that creates the response:

```
{..... //iterates throuh a result taken from the database
  $temp[0]=$id;
   $temp[1]=$squad_id;
   $result[]=$temp;
  }
  $result=json_encode($result);
  }
return $result;
}
```

if i call alert(response.constructor);
I get

```
function Array() {
    [native code]
}
```

**End Edit**

How do I iterate through a json array using jquery or javascript, or whatever works?

the json response i get has this form: [["1","12"],["2","3"],["3","7"]]

I should mention that using response.length; has no effect

```
function processSquads(response)
{
  alert (response[0][0]); // works and returns 1 
  alert (response[0]); // works and returns 1,12
  alert (response.length); //doesn't work so I can't iterate 
}
```

Sorry for the large number of questions today, but I'm just getting started with Ajax and I get stuck.

Comment: There's no JSON anywhere in your question.  It's a Javscript question, not JSON

Comment: Are you sure the response isn't `'{"0":["1","12"],"1":["2","3"],"2":["3","7"]}'`?

Comment: What do you get if you do `alert(response.constructor);`?

Comment: It's surely as I write it. And when I write alert(response.constructor) I got function Array() {
    [native code]
}

Comment: I managed to make it work although I have no idea what of the changes I made made it work. I am sure it was a ', ) ; or something of the sort :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Jquery:

```
var arr = [["1","12"],["2","3"],["3","7"]];
jQuery.each(arr, function() {
  alert(this[0] + " : " + this[1]);
});
//alerts: 1 : 12, etc.
```

This iterates the array and then shows what is in index 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

that's not a json array, it's an array of arrays

this should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/w6HUV/2/

```
var array = [["1", "12"], ["2", "3"], ["3", "7"]];

processSquads(array);

function processSquads(response) {
    alert(response[0][0]); // 1
    alert(response[0]); // 1, 12
    alert(response.length); // 3

    $(array).each(function(i){
        alert(response[i]); // 1,12 - 2,3 - 3,7
    });
}
```

Comment: I edited the post with some more details. I now it looks like an array of arrays but surely I can't find the length of it. the exact code you wrote -and I know is correct, just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this should work:

```
function processSquads(response)
{
  for(var list in response)
  {
    for(var item in response)
    {
      alert(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why jQuery answers are posted here, but you should find out why the `length` property is not working when it should. Posting the jQuery code from one of the answers with hazelnut JavaScript.

```
var arr = [["1","12"],["2","3"],["3","7"]];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    console.log(item[0] + " : " + item[1]);
}
```

Can you post an reproducible example of what you're doing on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or some other site?

Comment: Its tagged jquery and he also asked for either jquery or javascript.